# Selenium + WinError 14001 -

Tags: python, windows, selenium

Can i get some help with error?

"[WinError 14001] The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail". 
that's the code i'm using (chromedriver is in the path of the code):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.youtube.com'
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Have you downloaded the ChromeDriver for selenium?

Comment: Update the question with error stack trace.

Comment: you were right. sorry

Answer (score 0):

I usually see this message when required VC++ Runtime is not installed (possibly this can happen for any dependency that uses dreaded side-by-side installation technology). Thanks to Microsoft, there is no way to know exactly, what is missing.